# How can I render api response in React?

Tags: reactjs, render

I am using sock.js topic subscription for getting data. I can type response to console with this;

```
        <div>
            <SockJsClient url='http://localhost:8080/websocket-example' topics={['/topic/currency']}
            onMessage={(msg) => {console.log(msg);}}
            ref={(client) => {this.clientRef = client}}>
            </SockJsClient>
        </div>
```

But i couldn't render it.

Questions;

1. I am making topic subscription in the render function. Do I have to
   do it on another function? If yes how can i achive that?
2. After the first question, i have to render it. Incoming messages;

{parity: "EURTRY", buy: 7.873162974672604, sell: 7.071410177380406}

{parity: "USDTRY", buy: 7.58763763316203, sell: 7.158500227651455}

I want to render it in a table. Using bootstrap for the table. Each message will be updated in the table by parity property. There can be a switch for it.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="currencies" class= "table table-hover" >
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Currency Pair</th>
                                <th>Buy</th>
                                <th>Sell</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                         
                            <tr>
                                <td>USDTRY</td>
                                <td id="usdTryBuy"></td>
                                <td id="usdTrySell"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EURTRY</td>
                                <td id="eurTryBuy"></td>
                                <td id="eurTrySell"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>GBPTRY</td>
                                <td id="gbpTryBuy"></td>
                                <td id="gbpTrySell"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EURUSD</td>
                                <td id="eurUsdBuy"></td>
                                <td id="eurUsdSell"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks for your valuable thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

iterate it using `map` function

array

```
let arr = [{parity: "EURTRY", buy: 7.873162974672604, sell: 7.071410177380406},
  {parity: "USDTRY", buy: 7.58763763316203, sell: 7.158500227651455}]
```

JSX

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="currencies" class= "table table-hover" >
     <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
       <th>Currency Pair</th>
       <th>Buy</th>
       <th>Sell</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                         
      {arr.map((item,i)=>
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>USDTRY: {item.parity}</td>
          <td id="usdTryBuy">{item.buy}</td>
          <td id="usdTrySell">{item.sell}</td>
      </tr>
        )}
     </tbody>
  </div>
 </div>
```